# How large is Oscuro's Oblivion Overhaul, and is it free?

Tags: mods, the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

There is this mod called Oscuro's Oblivion Overhaul that I would like to try out. Does anyone know how large it is (in Mb) and where I can download it, and is it free to download or should I first buy it?

I already clocked this game without mods and would like to try something different with it now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Oscuro's Oblivion Overhaul is one of the best mods for Oblivion, in my opinion.

You can download it from [Oscuro's site](http://www.oscurogamedesign.com/oscurosoblivionoverhaul-down-high.html), [Planet Elder Scrolls](http://planetelderscrolls.gamespy.com/View.php?view=OblivionMods.Detail&id=3953) or [TES Nexus](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=15256). The initial download size is not that big, only 23 MB for the latest version (1.33), although the installer then downloads the actual mod, which takes up approx. 1 GB of space, from what I remember. [Here](http://devnull.sweetdanger.net/OOO/OOO_Guide.html) is an installation and quick-start guide.

I would also recommend installing the [Unofficial Oblivion Patch](http://planetelderscrolls.gamespy.com/View.php?view=OblivionMods.Detail&id=1417) (compatible with OOO), as it fixes thousands of bugs left over from the official patches.

To quote Raven Dreamer:

> Don't forget the [unofficial oblivion
>   patch supplemental](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=27710). The UOP introduces
>   a major bug regarding the Fort Sutch
>   Oblivion Gate, but the supplemental
>   fixes this, among other things

Good luck!

Comment: Actually OOO is much larger than 23MB. Closer to 400MB for the base.

Comment: Yes. That 23Mb is *just* the installer. The actual download is around 400Mb. Some players should opt to skip mucking around with the installer and just get the whole package at one go, especially if they're using a mod manager.

Comment: It says right there: "download size is 23 MB, but the installed mod takes up approx. 1 GB, from what I remember". I wasn't trying to suggest that it's a small mod, I pointed out that a lot more than 23 MB will be needed in order to enjoy OOO.

Comment: I had OOO at point, but I used it like once, then formatted my pc. Thats why i need to "try it out" again

Comment: Don't forget the [unofficial oblivion patch supplemental](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=27710). The UOP introduces a major bug regarding the Fort Sutch Oblivion Gate, but the supplemental fixes this, among other things.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I had forgotten about that one.

Comment: 1.33 is NOT the latest version; the PlanetElderScrolls links gives a 1.34beta5.

Comment: @Raven Dreamer: (and everyone else interested, I guess): FYI, Kivan is working on UOP again (the current version is [3.4.0](http://forums.bethsoft.com/index.php?/topic/1229692-wipunofficial-oblivion-patch-uop-v340/)), and he incorporated the UOP supplemental parts into the new version. So no need for them anymore.