# Is it possible to stop monster respawns in Oblivion?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-iv-oblivion

Is it possible to stop monsters from respawning in Oblivion ? Is it also possible to prevent monsters from auto-leveling with your character?

Comment: There are two discrete questions in the body.

Answer (score 6):

Sure it is, it just requires finding the [right mod.](http://tesnexus.com/).

Mods affecting the spawn rates and leveled encounter lists are a dime a dozen, so I won't bother to recommend specifics. (Similarly, not having used any, I feel unqualified.) Browse reviews and enjoy.

Answer (score 2):

Concerning the leveling, I [can](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21499/should-i-use-oscuros-oblivion-overhaul-when-playing-oblivion-for-the-first-time) recommend [Oscuro's Oblivion Overhaul](http://www.oscurogamedesign.com/oscurosoblivionoverhaul-desc-high.html).

Answer (score 2):

[Martigen's Monster Mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/oblivion/mods/17784) should fix your monster leveling problem. One of its features is:

> Statically scaled levelling -- meet creatures and NPCs more powerful than you, and less powerful than you, regardless of your level as you level.